# Load C++ shared library into Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, shared-libraries, mex

i tried to load a C++ shared library called [G+Smo](http://gs.jku.at/trac/gismo/wiki/WikiStart) into MATLAB 2016b on Linux. After compiling of G+Smo i got a shared object file "gismo.so".

I tried to load this library with the Matlab command: "loadlibrary". It was not successful because this command only supports functions that are written in C. In order to load a C++ library, i have to write a C Wrapper around the code or create a [mex](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-mex-files-1.html)-interface for it. Both are just much work and not trivial.

Is there any simple way to load this G+Smo project into Matlab?

Comment: declaring your functions as `extern 'C'` is too much work?

Comment: there are about 200 header files, which contain large amount of functions an subroutines. That will cost me a lot of time. Do i have to declare any function as extern 'C'?